# Parsing JSON from URL with PHP

Tags: php, json

After googling, implementing code upon code, I still cannot get ANYTHING to display. Nothing. Not one thing.

I have a URL spitting out JSON:

```
 {"videos":[{"video":{"name":"Sanyo Zio","youtube":"FxxLDr--R5A","post_date":"2010-10-08 01:00:00",...
```

Here's the code I'm using to access the page:

```
 $url = file_get_contents("http://[website]/json/test.json");

 $arr = json_decode($url,true);
```

Now here's a short list of what I've tried to access ANY data from the page:

1:

```
 print_r($arr);
```

2:

```
 foreach($arr['videos']['video'] as $item) {
   echo "Name: ". $item[0] ."<br>"; 
 }
```

3:

```
 $obj = $arr[0];
 echo $obj;
```

4:

```
 foreach($arr as $a){
   echo "Name: ".$a['videos']['video']['name']."<br />";
 }
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but I just haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong! Is my encoding not correct? Here's how I'm encoding the JSON to begin with:

```
 $arr = array('videos' => array());
 foreach($vid as $items){
  $arr['videos'][] = array('video' => array(
    'name' => $items['videoName'], 'youtube' => $items['youtubeID'], 'post_date' => $items['productionTimestamp'], 'description' => $items['videoDesc'], 'link' => $single_linker_values['deeplink'], 'image' => $image));
 }
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

---

Update - Apparently the server is locked down, but being inhouse I don't notice :) Obviously the webpage does! Thanks for the help!

Comment: The URL? Have you tried `var_dump()`?

Comment: So what does `print_r($arr);` show?  What's the problem here?

Comment: `var_dump($url);` before you try to parse anything, to see if you actually have a response at all.

Comment: print_r($arr); doesn't show anything, which leads me to believe the issue is either with the retrieval or the encoding.

Comment: Did you check your PHP file encoding?

Comment: var_dump($url); spits out: bool(false)

Comment: How would I check my PHP file encoding?

Comment: Can you just post the url? JSON or file encoding is not the problem here. `file_get_contents()` is failing to fetch the url. The problem is in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data
>   is deeper than the recursion limit

Since you are not specifying a recursion limit, chances are that either your JSON is invalid or nothing is being retrieved from your URL.

Three things to try:

- determine if there was a json_decode error

  `print_r(json_last_error()); // call after json_decode`
- check that data is being returned

  `print_r($url);`
- see if data will decode as an object

  `$obj = json_decode($url);`

  `print_r($obj);`

Comment: print_r(json_last_error()); spits out a 0.

print_r($url); spits out nothing.

Comment: So there is the problem, $url is empty meaning `file_get_contents("http://[website]/json/test.json");` is not retrieving anything.  Can you provide the full URL and we can check?

Comment: I've added the URL to my original question.

Comment: Your URL is returning a `204 No-Content` response

Comment: That would explain it. Server locked down. Guess I'll find another way. Thanks!